# Lambda Function - An Interesting Question

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have an interesting question regarding the lambda function in python. I would love to hear from you a brilliant explanation.

```
short_list = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
func_1 = lamda x: x*2 
func_2 = lamda x: x - x.mean()
```

When we use **func_1** on **short_list**, we pretty much multiply each element with 2.

And when apply **func_2** on **short_list**, we subtract each element with the mean of the short_list.

**My question is**: since x in the lambda function represent each element in the list, how come python can understand x.mean() as the mean of the short_list?

Any explanation is welcomed, and thank you so much for your help!

Comment: "how come python can understand `x.mean()` as the mean of the `short_list`?" - well, it doesn't "understand" that `x` is the same as `short_list`. In fact, the `lambda`s don't care what you pass as the argument - they just need _some_ `x`, whatever it is.

Comment: "since x in the lambda function represent each element in the list": That depends on how you use the `lambda`. If you do `func_1(short_list)`, `x` is the *entire* array; not 
a single element. It may be though the numpy has implemented its own mapping behavior that treats operations on the list as operations on the elements themselves. That has nothing to do with `lambda`s though.

Comment: In fact, when you do func_2(short_list) :  the `x` in `lambda` refers to what you sent as argument which is in this case your short_list so when it calls `x.mean()` in fact it calls `short_list.mean()` . 
Remember: the x in lambda refers to the argument passed

Comment: Try `short_list + 1` or `short_list - 3`. What results do you get?

Comment: @ForceBru Thank you so much for your comment! I got it!

Comment: @Carcigenicate Got it!

Comment: @kaouther I completely agree with your point that x refers to the argument passed!

Comment: @jarmod That is a great example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are working with an np.array, and therefor x is a vector.

func_1 = x*2 is the same as short_list * 2.  If you pass it an np.array the array is multiplied by 2.  (This is not applied element wise - it is applied to the entire vector at once)

func_2 is the same as short_list - the scalar short_list.mean().  This will result in an np.array with each element - the scalar short_list.mean() again not applied element wise, but as a vector)

The bottom line is every operation is on the np.array directly and not on its elements.  There is no loop.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I understand it now! It is funny I always think x implies the element!

Comment: Great!!  Glad to help.